# The php file for sending user data in a database is not giving any results. What should i do?

Tags: android

i want to know whether i am doing the right coding in PHP or there is some issue with my app which will be true if this PHP[register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stwwh.png) code is working. i have tried many times but the data would not go to server.

Comment: Please attach a minimal example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Because You did not Put anything in Values use Insert query like below

```
"INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('Mary', 'Moe', 'mary@example.com')"
```